# Showing image depending on database value in php

Tags: php, html

I am trying to show image. I have an image named 5.png. And my database value **$bnr_value** also returns 5 correctly. but image does not show. How can I fix it?

```
<img src="new_img/header/career/"<?php echo $bnr_value.'png'; ?> alt="" class="image" style="max-width: 100%; ">
```

Comment: Your double quotes for `src=` are wrong.  `<img src="SOMETHING" alt="" ...>`.  Here you close `"` before the `<?php`.  You should remove it and add a new one right after `?>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
 <img src="new_img/header/career/<?php echo $bnr_value.'.png'; ?>" alt="" class="image" style="max-width: 100%; ">
```

Comment: Where is folder/directory , images are going after uploading?

Comment: <img src="new_img/header/career/<?php echo $bnr_value.'.png'; ?>" alt="" class="image" style="max-width: 100%; ">  is updated answer

Answer (score 0):

//try this ..

```
 <img src="new_img/header/career/<?php echo $bnr_value.'.png'; ?>" alt="" class="image" style="max-width: 100%; ">

=> "new_img/header/career/" is a not a full path .. 

Example :- "new_img/header/career/<?php echo $bnr_value.'.png'; ?>" //  set like this .
```

Comment: <img src="new_img/header/career/5.png" alt="" class="image" style="max-width: 100%; ">   IT WORKS

Comment: Check now my answer .

Comment: Instead of including the website, you can add a `/` to the beginning of value of `src`. Same end result without having to care about the website. `<img srx="/new_img/header/caree/...`